# Symfony app login and Sonata admin dashboard login

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

In my app I have 2 parts, a frontend generated manually and a backend dashboard generated with Sonata admin. And I have an issue with the login of both parts:

**app/config/security.yml**

```
security:

encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
    m_and_m\UsuariosBundle\Entity\Usuarios: { algorithm: sha512, iterations: 10 }
    m_and_m\ClientesBundle\Entity\Clientes: { algorithm: sha512, iterations: 10 }

access_control:
    # URL of FOSUserBundle which need to be available to anonymous users
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    # Admin login page needs to be access without credential
    - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    # Secured part of the site
    # This config requires being logged for the whole site and having the admin role for the admin part.
    # Change these rules to adapt them to your needs
    - { path: ^/admin/login ,role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/logout ,role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/* ,role: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN,TOTAL] }

    - { path: ^/usuarios/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/usuarios/registro, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/usuarios/*, roles: ROLE_USUARIO }
    - { path: ^/clientes/*, roles: ROLE_CLIENTES }


role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:     [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN,ROLE_USUARIO,ROLE_CLIENTE]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
    #SONATA:
        #- ROLE_SONATA_PAGE_ADMIN_PAGE_EDIT # If you are using acl then this line must be commented

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_manager

    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [usuarios, clientes]
    usuarios:
        entity: { class: m_and_m\UsuariosBundle\Entity\Usuarios, property: email }
    clientes:
        entity: { class: m_and_m\ClientesBundle\Entity\Clientes, property: email }



firewalls:


    # -> custom firewall for the admin area of the URL
    admin:
        pattern:            /admin(.*)
        context:            user
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            login_path:     /admin/login
            use_forward:    false
            check_path:     /admin/login_check
            failure_path:   /admin/login
        logout:
            path:           /admin/logout
            target:         /admin
        anonymous:          true
    # -> end custom configuration

    # default login area for standard users

    frontend:
        pattern:    ^/*
        context:    frontend
        provider:   chain_provider
        anonymous:  ~
        form_login:
            login_path: usuarios_login
            check_path: usuarios_login_check
        logout:
            path: usuarios_logout
```

**UsuariosBundle/Resources/config/services.yml**

```
services:
usuarios.admin.usuarios:
    class: m_and_m\UsuariosBundle\Admin\UsuariosAdmin
    arguments: [~, m_and_m\UsuariosBundle\Entity\Usuarios, SonataAdminBundle:CRUD]
    tags:
        - {name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: Usuarios(Admin), label: Usuarios}

login_listener:
    class:      m_and_m\UsuariosBundle\Listener\LoginListener
    arguments:  [@security.context, @router]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login }
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response }
```

Following the doc I have created a `LoginListener` in my `usuariosbundle`.
When I log in from the frontend all goes perfect. But the Sonata admin dashboard login goes to the `LoginListener.php` file and returns an error:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User::getNombre() in
>   C:\wamp\www\m_and_m\src\m_and_m\UsuariosBundle\Listener\LoginListener.php
>   line 24

**LoginListener.php**

```
<?php
namespace m_and_m\UsuariosBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Componene\EventDispatcher\Event;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class LoginListener
{
private $contexto, $router, $usuario=null,$role=null;

public function __construct(SecurityContext $context, Router $router)
{
    $this->contexto=$context;
    $this->router = $router;
}

public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
{
    $token = $event->getAuthenticationToken();
    $this->usuario = $token->getUser()->getNombre();
    $this->role = $token->getRoles();
    $this->role=$this->role[0]->getrole();
    if($this->role=='ROLE_CLIENTE' && $token->getUser()->getActivo()==false){
        $this->usuario = null;
    }
}

public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
{
    if(null != $this->usuario)
    {
        if($this->role=='ROLE_USUARIO'){
            $portada=$this->router->generate('portada_usuario');
        }
        else{
            $portada=$this->router->generate('portada_cliente');
        }

        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($portada));
        $event->stopPropagation();
    }
}
}
?>
```

And I don´t know why is this happening, cause both providers are in different context. Do I need to do something more to separate both logins?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a method that does not exist in that entity. If you pay attention in the error you will see that the user class that comes from the token is not the one you think it is.